# how to enable vertical scroll in panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

How to enable vertical scroll in panel ?

I adding background image to panel which is larger than the panel size. I want to have vertical scroll bar which can be scrolled to show rest of the image.

I am using C# to create windows application.

Comment: The tags you selected don't make any sense. Is this question about ASP.NET or is it about WinForms? Those are two completely different things. With ASP.NET you can create a website/webpage and with WinForms you will create a traditional desktop application like Calculator or Paintbrush. Please make your mind and choose only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net:

```
<asp:Panel id="panel1" runat="server"
Height="200px" Width="100px" ScrollBars="Vertical">
```

you can also set scrollbars values to: `None, Horizontal, Vertical, Both, Auto`.

For Windows:

```
Panel myPanel = new Panel();
myPanel.ScrollBars="Vertical";
```